# Using one Vendor Folder for Multiple Projects in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to make multiple laravel projects for my task in university. But i have a problem with my disk capacity, i have very little space.

vendor folder is taking much space of my disk, and every laravel project use the same vendor folder without editing them. And I thought i could use the same Vendor Folder to reduce my disk consumption, but i don't know how to do that.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could use symlinks probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create `symlinks` in each project except whatever the main one is that actually has the vendor directory.

```
cd /var/www/SiteA
composer install

# create new project into /var/www/SiteB
cd ../SiteB

# If vendor directory is already there, delete it: rm -rf vendor
# create symlink to Site A's vendor directory
ln -s /var/www/SiteA/vendor
```

It's just Linux commands and tricks.

Comment: is this should using command line to run it? bcoz my cpanel doesn't have command line.

Comment: Yes. it's a linux command @James ... is there any SSH in your panel ?

Comment: yes, there is. but my provider block it. i can't access my ssh using private keys. it always say `Network error: Connection time out`

Comment: You have many ways to create symbol links ... check this link https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel and you can also accept the answer :) @James