# Is there a way to use one Vendor for multiple projects with different seeder

Tags: laravel, composer-php, vendor

i was having issues on how vendor take too much place. Since my host has a limit on number of files and folders (INODES). So i found a solution to use one Vendor for multiple project in laravel through the following link : [Using one Vendor Folder for Multiple Projects in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115352/using-one-vendor-folder-for-multiple-projects-in-laravel-5-2).

In the following lines I put the vendor in **projectA**, then link the others projects to it.

In **projectA** everything works well when i do `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
When i try the same thing to projectB for example, the above command works till it arrives where the seeders should be executed. There, some error occur due to the fact that the command is trying to launch a seeder of **projectA** in the **projectB** as shown in the following screenshot.

[Seeder Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k9OL.png)

So i want to know if there's a way to make the seeder separately.

I tried to create a symlink on the composer.json file as it was done for the vendor folder,  but it doesn't work.

I'm using Laravel 8

Comment: Try `composer dump-autoload` before running seeder

Comment: Have you tried to point vendor directory for both projects to the same directory usin https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir ?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your feedback. @AndriyLozynskiy i tried the dump-autoload but still face the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

I thínk this is a terrible idea, except in the case that both projects share exact same codebase.

Composer use composer.json as you know. How does your B project composer file determines how to resolve PSR4 autoload entries in Laravel, If it is symlinked to A project? That is probably the reason why your seed command is trying to locate Classes in A project.

Composer is clever enough to cache downloaded packages and reuse them, but I think that **every project has its own dependencies** and **state**, which is maintained by composer.json in the first case and composer.lock on the state case.

What happen if you update composer in A but not in B, will B work?

And last, composer autoload file reference all satisfied dependencies in your project, and in this case that (unique) autoload file will be loaded in both projects but what happen if your required packages are not exactly the same? ie You have Laravel Debug Bar in one project but not in the other. The autoload generated file will reference that package that will not exist on your other project.

Is not this the way composer work? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Composer the Vendor Directory (`vendor` in the project tree by default) is *per project*.

You ask about how to use one vendor folder for different projects.

Now first of all, this is absolutely not what Composer expects nor how it works. See [*Manuel Glez* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72680731/367456). In short *a terrible idea*.

When it comes to Composer, the place to share the actual PHP code across projects is not in the vendor directory but in [repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repositories).

And as long as the dependencies are compatible, you could make one project depend on another and use its `vendor/<vendor>/<name>` folders as repositories. The remarks in *Manuel Glez* answer are still the same, this need to be same compatible versions across the board.

But to give the example, see [Composer Path Repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) which has this layout:

```
...
├── apps
│   └── my-app
│       └── composer.json
├── packages
│   └── my-package
│       └── composer.json
...
```

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ]
}
```

It can be adopted for each `../../project/A/vendor/<pkg-vendor>/<pkg-name>` in `../../project/B/composer.json` so that the `vendor` folder in `project/A` can act as a path repository for `project/B`.

As dependencies `composer.json` files normally do not contain the version, the documented remarks about `repositories.options.versions` apply:

> When the version cannot be inferred from the local VCS repository, or when you want to override the `version`, you can use the versions option when declaring the repository:
>
> ```json
> {
>     "repositories": [
>         {
>             "type": "path",
>             "url": "../../packages/my-package",
>             "options": {
>                 "versions": {
>                     "my/package": "4.2-dev"
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```

To prevent the duplication of the files the default strategy for Composer is to `symlink` the package directories. Ensure it works, then you only have one symbolic link per dependency in project B.

Okay how cool is that? Well IMHO while you still give up much of what Composer can do for you for dependency management, this at least makes use of local Composer repositories which I'd recommend for sharing instead of completely symlinking the overall `vendor` folder. Each project still have its own `vendor/composer` setup and overall what is done is much more well defined and in line with Composer itself.

Whether this works or not depends on the individual case. Key point here is as these local repositories only provide a single version per each package, you can only have that one. So these versions must all be version compatible on API level.

The system where it runs needs to support (relative) symbolic links, this should be commonly available for the situation described.

You could then automate the production of the repositories configuration and adopt it to the file-system layout. You could even generate the repositories and update them in the global configuration file so that each project would automatically prefer those packages from local.

```bash
$ echo "$(composer config --global home)/config.json"
/home/user/.config/composer/config.json
```

*(compare: [`COMPOSER_HOME/config.json` (Composer docs)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home-config-json))*

Take care all projects and their dependencies have a portable path-profile and then I'd say this should be quite straight forward shell processing.

To obtain the actual versions of the dependencies installed check per each `vendor` folder inside `vendor/composer/*installed*` files.

```bash
$ (echo "PACKAGE VERSION"; find .. -type f -path '*/vendor/composer/installed.json' -exec jq -r '.packages[] | .name + " " + .version_normalized ' {} \; | sort -u | sort -k 1b,2V) | cols
PACKAGE                                        VERSION
composer/ca-bundle                             1.3.2.0
composer/composer                              2.3.7.0
composer/metadata-minifier                     1.0.0.0
composer/pcre                                  3.0.0.0
composer/semver                                3.3.2.0
composer/spdx-licenses                         1.5.7.0
composer/xdebug-handler                        3.0.3.0
...
phar-io/manifest                               1.0.1.0
phar-io/manifest                               1.0.3.0
phar-io/manifest                               2.0.1.0
phar-io/manifest                               2.0.3.0
...
```

(very old installations don't have the `packages` keyword, you'll likely want to filter)

Finally you may want to have something to smoke-test the setup easily so that you can have guards against the dependency incompatibility problems when you take notice of them.

Comment: Hello, Thank for your feed back. In addition of waht @ManuelGlez said... here i think, since all projects i'm trying to symlink work on different versions, i won't be able to realize what i mentioned in my post. I'm not so keen in compser and vendor, and this is going to a high level for me. So i'll maintain a vendor for each project then see how to eliminate some useless files and folders if possible.

Comment: The benefit with this method is that you would only have as many duplicates as necessary. This also includes the Laravel packages. Are you running composer install on the target server or are you using a build box? If you run it on the server, you also have the composer cache directory which may grow over time.

Comment: I run `composer update` on each deployment. As for the composer cache... i wish i could use `composer clear-cache`

Comment: In other hand... when i check the number files and folder of my project, it count up to 17 553 ( 11 452 files and 6101 folders ). Next when i check only the vendor files and folder... i notice it's the vendor that take to much as it count up to 14 156 in total ( 9708 files and 5078 folders ). So i check on other posts.. i remove fakerphp from the composer. I will checkup unnecessary folder from the vendor then remove them from the composer.json. Here i'm seeing it lessen a little bit the number of files and folders since it's the main reason i'm running to this issues

Comment: That sounds a bit you could benefit from installing with `--no-dev` as normally you don't need dev dependencies in production. Just in case you don't know that switch (both `update` and `install`, compare https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i)